# C# want to enable some disabled tab pages in a program and I have its source code

Tags: c#, properties, decoding, tabpage

In the source code designer it works fine after I press run its color fades and I can't use all the tab controls, please help and thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi0B0.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwtkH.jpg

Comment: So, where did you search???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go through your source code and search for "IsReadOnly". I assume that at some point the code is setting this to true as well as adjusting some other properties. it may be embedded in its own method which is called upon when the program executes because some pre-existing conditions are not met.

You should add a breakpoint just before that section of the program is loaded and then slowly step through it to find where properties and text-box values are being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for in the code for controllers disabled programmatically.